# SMW Table, only show results with a set value

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

When i use a SMW table

```
{{#ask: [[Category:XY]]

 |?Referenzwert
 |format=table
 |limit=1000

}}
```

I only want to see the pages in the property "Referenzwert" that have the value 1.

Is that possible or do i need to create various properties that use the "allows value" special property?

I have not found any answers in the SMW documentation, neither the normal Mediawiki documentation.

Comment: Do you want to see the pages, for which the property `Referenzwert` has the value `1`, or what?

Comment: Yes, that it exactly it

Comment: Then you should add `[[Referenzwert::1]]` to the first parametre (query condition) of the `{{#ask:}}` function.